# What arguments can be passed to npm-view command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, npm

I am reading documentation about npm and found an interesting command called [npm-view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-view).

It looks rather useful, but documentation looks weird.

```
npm view [<@scope>/]<name>[@<version>] [<field>[.<subfield>]]
```

First of all I would be glad if someone can explain or give a link where I can read what does all that
`[[<[].>@<>/<><>///]]` stuff mean, I've seen it plenty of times in different documentations, but no one never explain what is it.

Second I would like to know what does `<field>` option mean, because documentation says nothing about it. I can figure out that `<name>` stands for package name and `[@<version>]` stands for package version (looks like brackets are put around optional parameters), but `<field>`... How am I supposed know what should be put there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets indicate optional tokens. So in the example above, `npm view <name>` is the minimal syntax, but you can further qualify name with @scope/name@version like @someorg/somerepo@0.0.1.  The npm view documentation does further explain the details of it, but not specifically the shorthand.

As for `<field>`, if you run `npm view somepackage` you would see all the output of `npm view` broken out into different sections, like 'dist', 'dependiencies', 'maintainers', etc... These are the fields it's referring to.  The docs aren't explicit, but the examples of its usage try to illustrate this.